# Bash script. During execution - stdout + stderr in terminal, also stdout + stderr to file and again stderr to another file. Is that even possible?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, stdout, stderr

I have written multi-os provisioning script for local and aws ec2 VMs.

I want to achieve this behaviour of the script:

1. Execution
2. It shows **`stdout`** and **`stderr`** in terminal during execution
3. Simultaneously it records all stdout + stderr to `provision-full.log`
4. And also records all **`stderr`** to another file `provision-err.log`

Is that possible at all? I have googled a lot for the solution with no success. Am I miss something? I mean, maybe it's impossible to do by system design :)

The provision script has this design:

```
#!/bin/bash
# defining functions
{
  # some script here
} |& tee ~/full-provision.log
```

The closest solutions that I have been able to achieve:

1. `|& tee ~/full-provision.log` for local VMs, so I could see output in terminal and later I'm able to inspect `full-provision.log`
2. `2> /var/log/provision-err.log > /var/log/provision-out.log` for aws ec2 VMs with 2 separate log files for inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate standard error by redirecting it to process substitution `tee /var/log/provision-err.log`:

```
{ { # some script here } 2> >(tee /var/log/provision-err.log 1>&2); } |&
  tee ~/full-provision.log
```

The only subtlety is that the standard output of the process substitution shall be redirected back to the standard error (`1>&2`) if we want to preserve the separation between standard output and standard error. If you don't care the following shall work about the same:

```
{ { # some script here } 2> >(tee /var/log/provision-err.log); } |
  tee ~/full-provision.log
```

Note that this works only if your OS supports named pipes.

Comment: Thank a lot for clean explained answer! Worked as expected! I should definitely dig into Linux books.